# How to set default permissions for libvirt VM files

Tags: kvm-virtualization, file-permissions, libvirt

When I create a new virtual machine using `virt-manager`, a qcow2 file is created with read permission for all:

```
rw-r--r-- 1 libvirt-qemu libvirt-qemu  53695545344 Jan 12 16:24 vm.qcow2
```

I find it surprising that any user can read the content of the VM. I can restrict access to the parent directory, but what is the rationale for this?

Is there a way to set those permissions from `virt-manager`?

Is there a way to define a default umask for new VMs?

Investigating this, I'm wondering how the files are created in the first place since their directory is

```
rwxr-xr-x 2 root root
```

si only `root` can write in there.

I'm using `virt-manager` with my user with no special powers except being in `libvirt` group.

The host server is a Debian Jessie. The desktop that runs `virt-manager` is a Debian Jessie as well but I don't think that matters.

Comment: What Linux distribution are you referring to? RHEL and Fedora don't do this.

Comment: Debian Jessie. I'll double-check, then. But I'm pretty sure I didn't mess-up with that myself.